# How to use/read Sample Output Data from an App into webhook in our app in Zapier integration?

Tags: zapier

I have integrated my application with zapier. During a zap I can successfully perform an action in my application from an XYZ event from XYZ app.

I want to use sample data given by that XYZ app in my app and send it to my servers.

You can see sample output data from Mailchimp in the image below. I want to use that email field while triggering my action url:

[image]

Here is action endpoint body parameters. I can't can't get the email from Mailchimp sample data output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your app's configuration, you need two things:

1. A text `inputField` probably called `email` see [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/packages/cli#input-fields) (the linked docs are for the CLI, but the Visual Buidler uses the same structure)
2. In your `API Endpoint` section, you need to add `{{bundle.inputData.email}}` to the `value` in your second screenshot